# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Collection was of a fixed size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, ado.net-entity-data-model

I need some help in MVC Project that i am currently working on. I am trying to create a user with either a seller or buyer type. I Have created a many to many relationship as a user can be both a seller and a buyer. My Problem comes to inserting the role type I keep on getting the following error

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Collection was of a
>   fixed size.*

Below is the code that I am using

UserController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(UserModel data, string SellerType)
{
    try     
    {
        if(SellerType == "Buyer")
        {
            userType = 2;
        }
        else if (SellerType=="Seller")
        {
            userType = 3;
        }
        data.myUser.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        new UsersService.UserBLClient().RegisterUser(data.myUser, userType);   
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

ServiceReference

```
public RegistrationOutcome RegisterUser(Person newPerson,int userTypeId)
{
    if (DoesUserNameExist(newPerson.Username) == true)
    {
        return RegistrationOutcome.UsernameExists;
        throw new Exception("Username has already been registered");
    }
    if (DoesEmailExist(newPerson.Email) == true)
    {
        return RegistrationOutcome.EmailExists;
        throw new Exception("Email has already been registered");
    }
    else
    {
        DaRole rr = new DaRole();
        DaUser ur = new DaUser();
        rr.DataContext = ur.DataContext;
        ur.RegisterUser(newPerson);
        rr.AllocateUser(newPerson, rr.GetRoleById(userTypeId));
        return RegistrationOutcome.Success;
    }
}
```

The inserting and getting of the userrole

```
public void AllocateUser(Person newPerson, UserType roleType )
{
    newPerson.UserType.Add(roleType);
    DataContext.SaveChanges();
}

public UserType GetRoleById(int id)
{
    return DataContext.UserType.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RoleID == id);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take more care when formatting your code in the future - if it's all indented correctly, it makes it *much* easier for us to read and therefore help you. I've fixed it for this post.

Comment: What is `userType`? Where is it declared? Can you show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Usertype is whether the user is a seller or a buyer. It is declared in the DB and trying to allocate the user. May I ask you how do you show a stack trace ?

Comment: The line "new UsersService.UserBLClient().RegisterUser(data.myUser, userType);" doesn't look right. Btw, stack overflow usually means an infinite recursive happened somewhere.

Comment: Usertype there is getting the value from radio buttons to help get the correct value

Comment: You haven't posted which line in your code sample generates the exception. As someone already mentioned, there is most likely a infinite recursive call somewhere which is triggering this exception.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply the error is being generated here  newPerson.UserType.Add(roleType);

Comment: For some reason When i deleted my tables and re did them the code worked perfectfly.

Comment: 9 out of 10 times, recreating the tables fixes the update issue. Otherwise you must edit the Data Model to fix any issues (via Validate).